# can't find the output

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $age1 = isset($_POST['age1']) ? $_POST['age1'] : false;

    if ($age1 <= "18")
    {
    $sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.' and id = 1 ';
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['age1']) > "18")
    {
    $sql = 'select * from events where type_id='.$id.'';
    }

    $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql);
?>
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td class="style1">Date of Birth:</td>
      <td class="style2"><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control22" required autocomplete="off"></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <td class="style1">Age:</td>
    <td class="style2"><input type="text" name="age1" id="age1" class="form-control22" autocomplete="off"></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <td class="style1">Event Type:</td>
    <td class="style2">
        <select name="event_id" class="ddl" id="event_id" onchange="geteventprice()">
            <option value="0">--Select Event Type--</option>
                <?php while($evt= mysqli_fetch_object($tid)){
                echo   '<option value="'.$evt->id.'">'.$evt->name.'</option>'; } ?>
        </select>

   </td>
```

selecting a `dob` event will be show.
below eighteen age is different event and over 18 is different age. in above code i get only before else value.

Comment: false will also be less that 18. change the false in ```isset($_POST['age1']) ? $_POST['age1'] : false;``` to a numeric value.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['age1']) > "18")`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your else if condition will return false always even if age is greater than 18 because `isset($_POST['age1'])` will return bool(true) and your condition `> 18` will never satisfy

replace this code with

```
 else if (isset($_POST['age1']) > "18")


 else if ($age1 > 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because `else if (isset($_POST['age1'])` will be true or false and can not be `> 18` 
Do it like this;

```
$age1 = isset($_POST['age1']) ? $_POST['age1'] : false;
if($age1) {
  if($age1 <= 18) {
    $sql = "below 18";
  }
  if($age1 > 18) {
    $sql = "over 18";
  }
  echo $age1;
} else {
  echo 'no age given';
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f756d52ed64c2c1334f628a27312d2501b51395

Comment: there is a typo it must be `if($age1 <= 18) {...}` and `if($age1 > 18) {..}` i edited my answer

Comment: @Shri did you try the edited version of the answer? also see the sandbox link with working example

Comment: what kind of an error? See the example in the link, its working

Comment: <?php $age1 = isset($_POST['age1']) ? $_POST['age1'] : false;
     if ($age1)
     {
      if ($age1 <= 18)
      {
       $sql= "select * from events where type_id='.$id.' and id = 1";
      }
      if ($age1 > 18)
      {
       $sql= "select * from events where type_id='.$id.'";
      }
      $tid = mysqli_query($conid, $sql);
     }
     else 
     {
       echo 'no age given';
     } ?>                                                                      This is my code and error on $tid it show undefined variable

Comment: try `print_r($sql)` before `$tid = ...` and see if the `$sql` string is correct

Comment: yes link output is working. but when data call from database it don't change

Comment: try `print_r($tid)` right after `mysqli_query($conid,$sql)`